# How to control XML element names in Play framework

Tags: java, xml, playframework

I've got a java bean class, which i render using `renderXml` method. How to control the name of the class or fields in XMl. Something like this

```
@XStreamAlias(value="MyInfo")
public class Info  {
}
```

I want to render MyInfo instead of Info as parent element. As I can see, Play use XStream for rendering xml, but I can't figure out, how to change element name. I know, that it's possible to render with predefined template in view folder, I would like to avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("Info", Info.class);
    renderXml(callInfo, xstream);
```

It's possible to pass XStream instance with special properties. And everything works